# An XML parser that will allow handling individual tag parsing in a flattened way

Tags: node.js, xml, xml-parsing

I am looking for an XML parser that will allow handling individual tag parsing in a flattened way. Something that [this](https://github.com/CondeNast/xml-to-react) module does but server/node.js compatible. For example:

```
const xmlToReact = new someXmlParser({
  Example: (attrs) => {console.log("get all necessary info")},
  Item: (attrs) => {console.log("get all necessary info")}
});

const reactTree = someXmlParser.convert(`
  <Example name="simple">
    <Item i="1">one</Item>
    <Item>two</Item>
    <Item>three</Item>
  </Example>
`);
```

Comment: updated the answer :)

Comment: I've rolled back youir edit. It is not appropriate to ask a question, get it answered, and then alter that question to ask additional questions as well. If you have a new question, click the *Ask Question* button and ask it as a new question. In addition, questions asking us to recommend or find tools, software libraries or other off-site resources are off-topic. For more information, see the [help] guidelines.

Comment: Not sure if these policies are helpful to the community. People have different questions and needs. Thanks for moderation anyways!

Comment: Ah ok. @SaidAkh if you need the updated answer, you can always see the revision from here https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69538092/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think [camaro](https://www.npmjs.com/package/camaro) would fit your needs. you reshape the xml via the xpath template.

eg

```js
const { transform } = require('camaro')

const xml = `
<Example name="simple">
    <Item i="1">one</Item>
    <Item>two</Item>
    <Item>three</Item>
  </Example>
`
const template = {
    examples: ['/Example', {
        name: '@name',
        items: ['Item', '.']
    }]
}

async function main() {
    const output = await transform(xml, template)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 2))
}

main()
```

```json
{
  "examples": [
    {
      "name": "simple",
      "items": [
        "one",
        "two",
        "three"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thank you, @tuan-anh-tran! This module does almost exactly what I am looking for. Can you please see the updated question?

Comment: @SaidAkh updated the answer :) hope it helps